# Android activity navigation

Tags: java, android, navigation

I'm developing an app, where there is the main activity, it display some content (texts, images, etc), and a translucent menu on top of it. In this menu, I got link to other "screens" (implemented as Activities), on clicking it, I get correctly to the new activity, but the "activity changing animation" of the device blinks and then get me to the new activity.

I would like to make the navigation experience to be seamless on navigate through the screens, keeping my menu always on top of it. Today, this menu is implemented as a custom view (extending a Linear layout), also this menu will be expandable and collapsible, so the way it is I have to store the menu state through the activities.

**PS:** The way I've thought was to keep always two running activities, one for the current screen and another one for the menu, keep the menu on top, and just change the activity behind it. But could not find a way to do this...

**PPS:** Developing for Android 2.1

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html), or try to keep all functionality in one activity, changing only the content view.

Comment: Ok, it seems exactly what I'm looking for, BUT the docs says: "Android introduced fragments in Android 3.0 (API Level 'Honeycomb')...", I developing for 2.1. Can't test right now, but think it is not available, any workaround ?

Comment: You can use fragments in your application using the Android Compatibility Package, which can be installed from your AVD Manager.

Comment: Glad it was helpful to you! Good luck!