# Cannot move from login activity to admin category, sending back to main?

Tags: javascript, java, kotlin

Cannot move from login activity to admin category, sending back to main? After removing the `intent` & `findView` from admin category then login is ok.

```
if (parentDbName.equals("Admins"))
{
    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Welcome Admin, you are logged in Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    loadingBar.dismiss();

    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminCategoryActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
else if (parentDbName.equals("Users"))
{
    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "logged in Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    loadingBar.dismiss();

    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android activity navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520861/android-activity-navigation)

Comment: No dear its all about fragment. My issue is different. In my issue when click for admin login  and admin activity on defaults (without change anything) then ok. And when I write something like intent, findView by iD or toast then its not switching from login to admin activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found issue ,.....for solution....just delete that activity and create again it will work